# Grouping on Weekday histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter

I have a df in the format:

```
  date                    number     category
2014-02-02 17:00:00         4         red
2014-02-03 17:00:00         5         red
2014-02-04 17:00:00         4         blue
2014-02-05 17:00:00         4         blue
2014-02-06 17:00:00         4         red
2014-02-07 17:00:00         4         red
2014-02-08 17:00:00         4         blue
...
```

How do I group on day of the week and take a total of 'number' in that day of the week, so Id have a df of 7 items, monday, tuesday etc, and the total number of 'number' on that day. With this I want to make a histogram with number on the y and day of the week on the x.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question again, I understand why @Quang Hoang answered the way he did. Not so sure if that's what you had wanted or if the below is:

```py
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.day_name())

counts = df.groupby('day')['Number'].sum()
plt.bar(counts.index, counts)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dt.day_name()` to extract the day name, then use `pd.crosstab` to count the number:

```
pd.crosstab(df['date'].dt.day_name(),df['number'])
```

Output:

```
number     4  5
date           
Friday     1  0
Monday     0  1
Saturday   1  0
Sunday     1  0
Thursday   1  0
Tuesday    1  0
Wednesday  1  0
```

And to plot a histogram, you can chain the above with `.plot.bar()`:

[image]